# How can i list the git branches which are merged to master and delete the branches if it looks good?

Tags: git, github

I am working on a project and we are using git. I would like to delete the 
    branches with are merged. But before that i would like to list the branches, 
    so that i can review once. If it looks good to me then delete the branches.

I have seen some script which deletes the merged branches but i want to see 
    the list of branches before performing delete operation.

```
git branch -r --merged | grep origin | grep -v '>' | grep -v master | sed 
's/origin\///' | xargs git push origin --delete
```

Comment: then just run the `git branch --merged` bit alone

Answer (score 0):

If you want to visualize your branches, use git log:

```
git log --oneline --graph --all --decorate=short
```